# Do items on a list have to follow the order/logic of the previous one?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

This is a bit hard to explain, so here's an example:

> His room was an exact replica of mine. The only difference were the
>   things he had brought along: **his zoology books, his backpack, and of
>   course his climbing equipment.** Little objects that told me something
>   about him, but that at the same time, pushed him further away, into a mist
>   of **knowledge and practicality.**

As you can see, the second list follows the 'sequence' of the first one:

> Knowledge = zoology books
>
> Practicality = his backpack, climbing equipment

Do writers follow this rule? Or it doesn't matter?

The reason I ask is because I want to write *a mist of practicality and knowledge* instead (it sounds better to me for some weird reason).

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference which order you put them in, but I object to using "mist" to describe two very hard, down-to-earth concepts. *Knowledge* is concrete: I *know* something. *Practicality* is working with your hands, it's tactile, it's real. There is nothing nebulous or "misty" about either of those qualities.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I *think* the "mist" is intended to apply to the relationship, i.e., the narrator is not an intellectual and is perhaps more spontaneous than practical so the other person's focus on practicality and knowledge is alien (mysterious, difficult to grasp, separating, thus "misty"). The intent (I think) was to contrast ("but") the revelation of the other's nature (usually associated with drawing closer in relationship) with the separation from their differences (which was not like a wall or chasm but "misty").

Comment: A mist formed of many small items for storing and acquiring knowledge and items of practicality.

Comment: @what no, a mist is a fog, it's something you can't touch. A mist can't be formed of individual items.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I get the idea that the other person's knowledge puts him at a higher plane than the narrator, but then use "plane" or "pushed him out of my reach" or "obscured him from my sight" or something. The concept of "all this intelligence separates us" works. The word "mist" doesn't.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I experience mist as formed of many individual water droplets that I feel on my skin. But we are beginning to read a lot into that word, and I agree with you that there might be better ways to express whatever Alexandro wants to express here.

Comment: OK, I'll revise that part. Used to be worse, initially, I wrote a *vast ocean of knowledge and practicality.* (Or was it better? I'm not sure anymore).

Comment: *Ocean* is way better. It's a solid thing which is infinitely large and vast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question makes me come up with the following example:

> For twenty years I lived in the land of milk and honey - along with the bees and cows.

To me, this sounds better than:

> <s>For twenty years I lived in the land of milk and honey - along with the cows and bees.</s>

I can't explain (though I find Lauren Ipsum's explanation in the comment below quite plausible), and others might disagree, but my gut feeling says that in this case **it is better to reverse the order**.

---

Following up on the comments, "practicality and knowledge" sounds better to me than "knowledge and practicality", because `/ˈnɑlədʒ/` has only one stressed syllable, while `/ˌpræktəˈkælədi/` has at least two (and more syllables overall), which creates two rhythmic patterns:

```
knowledge and practicality
  /  x    x     /  x / x x

practicality and knowledge
  /  x / x x x     /  x

/ = stressed, x = unstressed; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scansion
```

The second rhythmic pattern ("p. and k.") has a distinctive finishing subpattern at the end (`/ x`), while the first pattern ("k. and p.") sort of "peters out".

Which pattern works better in your context would depend on **what kind of effect** you prefer: a strong, finalising statement ("p. and k.") or a more uncertain, open almost-question ("k. and p.").

Comment: you could add that the word often used to show the matching is "respectively", because often the order is changed for the benefit of rhythm, as you demonstrated. "I lived for twenty years in the land of milk and honey, made by the cows and bees, respectively" (Imagine you don't know what milk or honey is): "I lived in the land of Krush and Prill, made by the Mogobeasts and Rapticores, respectively"

Comment: [Chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus) is a common mechanism.

Comment: "Bees and cows" *sounds* better because of the vowels. It goes from EE (high sound) to OW (low sound). OW is a finishing sound. "Cows and bees" ends the thought on a high note, and it sounds jarring.

Comment: "Dot and dash your *i* s and *t* s" doesn't sound so nice to me, though, with or without "respectively," in that or another order.

Answer (score 0):

First, they don't *have* to, a one-to-one correspondence is not mandatory.

That said, they are two different narrative styles, the former simpler and faster to scan, the latter much superior literally, reflecting a creative twist added in. Occasional use of the latter can be enriching. (Also tests the reviewer's acuity.)

.